# How to correctly import the package org.json.simple into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, capacitor

I want to import the package "org.json.simple" in my Capacitor Plugin.

My Import:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

When I try to start the App in Android Studio I get the message:

> error: package org.json.simple does not exist
>
> import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

Other imports are working. Is there something I need to do additionally ?

Comment: Did you add the dependency? org.json.simple is not a standard library but a external dependency, check their docs about how to add the dependency to it.

Comment: I did not find any information on what dependencies are needed, and also I don't know how to add dependencies.

Comment: where did you hear about `org.json.simple`? why are you trying to use those instead of the standard `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONObject`? Those require no dependencies.
Wherever you read about  `org.json.simple` should mention how to add the dependency

Comment: @ Julio Cesar - I just tried org.json.JSONArray, and it works. At least, I'm getting a different error now that has nothing to do with the import. Feel free to post your comment as the Answer.